# How would I structure react components that must receive data from a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Right now my React container looks something like this:

```
class TableData extends Component
{
some React Functions and state changes. 
<Sidebar passdata as props/>

}
```

And inside the Sidebar I have a modal, that needs to update state to both the Sidebar component and TableData Component.

I do not know if you could pass props to the parent component in React but I know it is not recommended. What is the recommended course of action in these type of problems?

Comment: Are you using redux or something similar?

Comment: Not currently, should I be ? I only have these two components I am having this issue

Comment: Redux is useful for larger projects, but is not necessary for something small-scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot pass props to the parent component. However, the parent component can pass a callback as a prop to its children that is called when values change.

```
class TableData extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        // ...
        this.state = {
            name: originalState,
        };
    }

    handleStateChange(newState) {
        this.setState({ name: newState });
    }

    render() {
        // ...
        <Sidebar onStateChange={this.handleStateChange.bind(this)} />
        // ...
    }
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    // ...
    this.props.onStateChange(newState);
    // ...
}
```